# Kafka Streams API: write to sink if .groupByKey().count() matches itemCounter

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My Kafka Topic contains multiple items per key as well as an itemCounter per entry.
As soon as the counted number of items in the partition matches the itemCounter for the key, I want to write the repsective entries to another Kafka topic.

My idea was something like this, but I´m getting the following error:
"Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'long', 'org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long>'".

```
KStream<String, HeaderItem> stream = builder.stream(
                INPUT_TOPIC,
               Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), headerItemSerde));

stream.filter((key, value) -> value.itemCounter ==
                stream.filter((k, v) -> k.contentEquals(key)).groupByKey().count()).toStream().to(OUTPUT_TOPIC);
```

| Key | item | itemCounter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 001 | 3 |
| ABC | 002 | 3 |
| ABC | 003 | 3 |
| XYZ | 001 | 2 |
| XYZ | 002 | 2 |

Has someone an idea how to solve it? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a class to keep in state. This class should look like this;

```
    class TempClass {
    @JsonProperty("count")
        private int count;
    @JsonProperty("itemCounter")
        private int itemCounter;
public TempClass withitemCounter(int itemCounter) {
        this.itemCounter= itemCounter;
        return this;
    }
public TempClass withCount(int count) {
        this.count= count;
        return this;
    }
  }
```

Then make an aggregation;

```
stream.groupByKey().aggregate(
//Init
() -> new TempClass().withCount(0).withitemCounter(0),
(key,value,aggValue) -> new TempClass()
.withCount(aggValue + 1)
.withitemCounter(value.itemCounter);
)
```

Now you have count and itemCounter value per each key. After that you can filter or doing something different. Do that and write to result topic.
It was just a pseudocode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer and helpful idea! I am getting the following error: "Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'org.acme.kafka.streams.Counter', 'int'"

Comment: Make sure you are using counter as int.